# Efficient cross join with aggregation and filter

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, sqldf, cross-join

As per the title, I am looking to do a cross join with a table which performs an aggregation function and filters on a couple of variables within the table.

I have similar data to the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

sales <-  data.frame(salesx = c(3000, 2250,850,1800,1700,560,58,200,965,1525)
                     ,week = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
                     ,uplift = c(0.04)
                     ,slope = c(100)
                     ,carryover = c(.35))
spend <- data.frame(spend = seq(from = 1, to = 50000, by = 1))

tempdata <- merge(spend,sales,all=TRUE)
tempdata$singledata <- as.numeric(1)
```

And here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish via my sql based solution:

```
newdata <- sqldf("select a.spend, a.week,
                 sum(case when b.week > a.week
                 then b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power(b.singledata,b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend
                 else 0.0 end) as calc3
                 from tempdata a, tempdata b  
                 where a.spend = b.spend 
                 group by a.spend,a.week")
```

This provides the results I want, but it is a little slow, particularly with my real dataset of around 1 million records. It would be great to have some advice on a) how to speed up the sqldf function; or b) using a more efficient data.table/dplyr approach (I can't get my head around the cross join/aggregation/filter trifecta problem).

**Clarity on non-equi join solution below:**

I had a couple of questions about the non-equi join solution – output is fine and very quick. In looking to understand how the code worked, I broke it down like this:

```
breakdown <- setDT(tempdata)[tempdata, .(spend, uplift, slope,carryover,salesx,  singledata, week, i.week,x.week, i.salesx,x.salesx, x.spend, i.spend), on=.(spend, week > week)]
```

Based on the breakdown, in order to be consistent with the original calculation, it should be:

```
x.salesx*(uplift*(1.0-exp(-(`^`(singledata,x.week-week)/slope))))/i.spend
```

The reason why this isn’t apparent is because with the example I used the ‘power’ part of the equation wasn’t really doing anything (always 1). The actual calc used is (adding a carryover variable to data):

SQL

```
b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power((b.singledata*b.carryover),b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend (sql)
```

My data.table solution

```
sum(salesx.y*(uplift.y*(1-exp(-((singledata.y*adstock.y)^(week.y-week.x)/slope.y))))/spend), by=list(spend, week.x)
```

However, I am unable to get this working with the non equi join solution when adding the ‘carryover’ variable ie.

```
x.salesx*(uplift*(1.0-exp(-(`^`((singledata*carryover),x.week-week)/slope))))/i.spend
```

Comment: You loaded `data.table`, but then you don't do anything with it??? (generally it is better to break the process into steps.)

Comment: You maybe able to get your existing code to run faster if you add indexes.

Comment: Perhaps, it might be that `data.table`'s non-equi-join might be helpful here.  But, please, describe what your goal / intention is. There might be other approaches than just the existing solution which you are asking to improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016) of `data.table` *non-equi joins* were introduced which help to avoid memory-consuming cross joins:

```
library(data.table)
newdata4 <- 
  # coerce to data.table
  setDT(tempdata)[
    # non-equi self-join
    tempdata, on = .(spend, week > week), 
    # compute result
    .(calc3 = sum(salesx*(uplift*(1.0-exp(-(`^`(singledata,week-i.week)/slope))))/i.spend)), 
    # grouped by join parameters
    by = .EACHI][
      # replace NA
      is.na(calc3), calc3 := 0.0][]

# check that results are equal
all.equal(newdata, as.data.frame(newdata4[order(spend, week)]))
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

#### Benchmark

The OP has provided [three different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45964605/3817004) solutions, two `sqldf` variants and one `data.table` approach using a cross join. These are compared against the non-equi join.

The code below

```
dt_tempdata <- data.table(tempdata)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sqldf = {
    newdata <- sqldf("select a.spend, a.week,
                 sum(case when b.week > a.week
                     then b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power(b.singledata,b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend
                     else 0.0 end) as calc3
                     from tempdata a, tempdata b  
                     where a.spend = b.spend 
                     group by a.spend,a.week")
  },
  sqldf_idx = {
    newdata2 <- sqldf(c('create index newindex on tempdata(spend)',
                        'select a.spend, a.week,
                        sum(case when b.week > a.week
                        then b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power(b.singledata,b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend
                        else 0.0 end) as calc3
                        from main.tempdata a left join main.tempdata b  
                        on a.spend = b.spend 
                        group by a.spend,a.week'), dbname = tempfile())
  },
  dt_merge = { 
    newdata3 <- merge(dt_tempdata, dt_tempdata, by="spend", all=TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)[
      week.y > week.x, 
      .(calc3 = sum(salesx.y*(uplift.y*(1-exp(-(singledata.y^(week.y-week.x)/slope.y)))))), 
      by=.(spend, week.x)]
  },
  dt_nonequi = {
    newdata4 <- dt_tempdata[
      dt_tempdata, on = .(spend, week > week), 
      .(calc3 = sum(salesx*(uplift*(1.0-exp(-(`^`(singledata,week-i.week)/slope))))/i.spend)), 
      by = .EACHI][is.na(calc3), calc3 := 0.0]
  },
  times = 3L
)
```

returns these timings:

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>       sqldf  9.456110 10.081704 10.647193 10.707299 11.242735 11.778171     3   b
>   sqldf_idx 10.980590 11.477774 11.734239 11.974958 12.111064 12.247170     3   b
>    dt_merge  3.037857  3.147274  3.192227  3.256692  3.269412  3.282131     3  a 
>  dt_nonequi  1.768764  1.776581  1.792359  1.784397  1.804156  1.823916     3  a
> ```

For the given problem size, the non-equi join is the fastest, nearly twice as fast as the merge/cross-join `data.table` approach and 6 times faster than the `sqldf` codes. Interestingly, index creation and/or temp file usage seems to be rather costly on my system.

Note that I have streamlined OP's `data.table` solution.

Finally, all versions except the merge/cross-join (I have refrained from fixing this version) return the same result.

```
all.equal(newdata, newdata2) # TRUE
all.equal(newdata, as.data.frame(newdata3[order(spend, week.x)])) # FALSE (last week missing)
all.equal(newdata, as.data.frame(newdata4[order(spend, week)])) # TRUE
```

#### Larger problem size

The OP has reported that the merge/cross-join `data.table` solution runs out of memory for his production data set of 1 M rows. To verify the non-equi join approach consumes less memory, I have tested it with a problem size of 5 M rows (`nrow(tempdata)`) which is ten times larger than in the previous benchmark runs. On my PC with 8 GB of memory the run completed without problems in about 18 seconds.

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>  dt_nonequi 18.12387 18.12657 18.23454 18.12927 18.28987 18.45047     3
> ```

Comment: I had a couple of clarity questions regarding this solution - I added it to the bottom of the original question as a bit too long for a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally had time to investigate this again:

My original solution:

```
  system.time(newdata <- sqldf("select a.spend, a.week,
                   sum(case when b.week > a.week
                   then b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power(b.singledata,b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend
                   else 0.0 end) as calc3
                   from tempdata a, tempdata b  
                   where a.spend = b.spend 
                   group by a.spend,a.week"))

   user  system elapsed 
  11.99    3.77   16.11
```

With an index (although something tells me this isn't working properly):

```
system.time(newdata2 <- sqldf(c('create index newindex on tempdata(spend)',
                                    'select a.spend, a.week,
                                    sum(case when b.week > a.week
                                    then b.salesx*(b.uplift*(1-exp(-(power(b.singledata,b.week-a.week)/b.slope))))/b.spend
                                    else 0.0 end) as calc3
                                    from main.tempdata a left join main.tempdata b  
                                    on a.spend = b.spend 
                                    group by a.spend,a.week'), dbname = tempfile()))

   user  system elapsed 
  12.73    2.93   15.76
```

Data.table solution (doesn't return 0's from the ifelse statement in sql):

```
    datatablefunc <- function(g){
    tempdata2 <- as.data.table(g)
    setkey(tempdata2, spend)
    tempdata3 <- merge(tempdata2, tempdata2, by="spend", all=TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
    tempdata4 <-  tempdata3[week.y > week.x, sum(salesx.y*(uplift.y*(1-exp(-(singledata.y^(week.y-week.x)/slope.y))))/spend), by=list(spend, week.x)] 
    return(tempdata4)
  }
  system.time(newdata3 <- datatablefunc(tempdata))

   user  system elapsed 
   2.36    0.25    2.62
```

The beauty of the sql based solution is that because the temporary output is stored in the sql server and not in memory then I don't run into pesky 'cannot allocate vector' problems, which happens with the data.table/dplyr solutions (when I add more data)...the downside is it takes a bit longer to run.